# Subscriptable Type Hinting and Instance Checks

Tags: python, beginner, type-hinting

### Background

The `typing` module supports subscriptable types. Here is an example use case:

```py
from typing import List

def foo(bar: List[int]):
    pass
```

However, when you try to use this with `isinstance`, it fails:

```
>>> from typing import List
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> isinstance(my_list, List[int])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 719, in __instancecheck__
    return self.__subclasscheck__(type(obj))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 722, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

### Code

So, I wrote a program which can test for subscripted types. Here is my code:

```py
class Union:
    def __init__(self, type1, type2):
        if not isinstance(type1, (type, Type)) or not isinstance(type2, (type, Type)):
            raise ValueError(f'{type1!r}, {type2!r} are not types')
        self.types = type1, type2
    def __str__(self):
        return self.types[0].__name__ + ' | ' + self.types[1].__name__
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    @property
    def __name__(self):
        return str(self)

class Type:
    def __init__(self, dtype, of=None):
        if isinstance(dtype, Type):
            self.dtype = dtype.dtype
        elif isinstance(dtype, (type, Union)):
            self.dtype = dtype
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{dtype!r} is not a type')
        if of is not None and not isinstance(of, (Type, Union, type)):
            raise ValueError(f'{of!r} is not a type')
        self.of = of
    def __str__(self):
        if self.of is not None:
            return f'{self.dtype.__name__}[{str(self.of.__name__)}]'
        else:
            return str(self.dtype.__name__)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __getitem__(self, cls):
        return Type(self, cls)
    def __or__(self, other):
        return Union(self, other)
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return Union(other, self)
    @property
    def __name__(self):
        return str(self)

def IsInstance(obj, dtype):
    if isinstance(dtype, type):
        return isinstance(obj, dtype)
    elif isinstance(dtype, Type):
        if dtype.of is None:
            return isinstance(obj, dtype.dtype)
        return all(IsInstance(item, dtype.of) for item in obj)
    elif isinstance(dtype, Union):
        return any(IsInstance(obj, t) for t in dtype.types)

Bool = Type(bool)
Dict = Type(dict)
Float = Type(float)
Int = Type(int)
List = Type(list)
Set = Type(set)
Str = Type(str)
Tuple = Type(tuple)
```

### Notes

- `Union` is the equivalent of `typing.Union`, but it is a bit different. You can get a `Union` by either:

  - Using `Union(int, float)`
  - Using `Int | Float`
- To do the instance check, use `IsInstance`, not `isinstance`. For example:

  - Use `IsInstance([1, 2, 3], List[int])`

The code is also on [Github](https://github.com/nayakrujul/better-typing/blob/main/better_typing/bt.py), and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/better-typing)

Answer (score 1):

I get the motivation for doing this, but it crosses an important line - one that I've myself crossed and then somewhat regretted later.

There's only so much you can do to save Python from itself. The type system is weak, and will never be strong no matter how clever we attempt to be. [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) is explicitly about *static type analysis* and not *runtime type enforcement*.

You've implemented `IsInstance` to check for the hint, but crucially it never actually checks whether the associated data in runtime *match* the hint.

Also you've written `Type`, `Union`, `Dict`, `List`, `Set` and `Tuple` classes that, while they don't technically shadow their alternatives in the built-in `typing` module, are really not a good idea to name identically.

Please don't do any of this. Use of `isinstance` itself is very often an anti-pattern, but we can't say for sure because you haven't shown where this code is used. Frequent remedies to `isinstance` are class polymorphism, writing type-alternative front-end functions to a core logic function (since Python has no signature overloading), etc.

Comment: *"You've implemented `IsInstance` to check for the hint, but crucially it never actually checks whether the associated data in runtime match the hint."* - I didn't want to do that. If I want to check the type, I'll do it explicitly by calling `IsInstance`.

Comment: You're doing something that should be done by mypy and not you, in static time and not runtime, and you're failing to actually validate runtime data. So I think what you want to do is a problem.